# Groovy - Class name must start with a capital letter for coercion?

Tags: groovy

EDIT: I am simplifying the question since I am getting down votes with no answers

I am calling a groovy script from the command line on Windows (`groovy ClassIssue.groovy`)
Groovy version 2.4.5 JVM 1.8.0_51

Also tested on Linux with Groovy 2.4.6

Why does this work:

```
class Person {
  String name
  Person() {}
}

Person p = [name: 'Jahg']
```

But this does not:

```
class person {
  String name
  person() {}
}

person p = [name: 'Jahg'] // this line throws an exception
```

The only difference is the class starts with a lower case.

Comment: You should always name your classes starting with a capital letter anyway.

Comment: That is true - but I would still like to know why this happens...

Answer (score 0):

(Should have  been a comment, using answer for formating )

Groovy compiler does lot of [meta programming magic](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html) to convert your script/groovy class to Java class for JVM.  It has fair bit of rules to handle properties and methods.

Your current Script becomes a class first. Its Name is derived from scriptname. Inside that class,  mc is assigned the array.

```
mc = ['123', 'Jahg']
```

Then it becomes a call to a method `myClazz`

When you name the class with upper case, the this

```
myClazz mc
```

Which fails as there is no `myClazz` method

Comment: I understand that a lot happens under the hood but I don't follow your explanation as to why it can't call myClazz

Comment: I think you are assuming that I didn't rename all the references to MyClazz:  MyClazz mc = ['123', 'Jahg']